# Why is the number of ordered pairs of disjoint subsets of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ not $20$?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> Let $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. The number of different ordered pairs $(Y,Z)$ that can be formed such that $Y \subseteq X$, $Z \subseteq X$ and $Y \cap Z$ is empty is $\underline{\hspace{15pt}}$.

The given answer is $3^5$.

But I know a ordered pair is composed of two elements. Thus if $Y=\{1\}$, $Z = \{2\}$ or $\{3\}$ or $\{4\}$ or $\{5\}$. Again if $Y=\{2\}$, $Z=\{1\}$ or $\{3\}$ or $\{4\}$ or $\{5\}$. Similarly....

Thus the number of ordered pairs needs to be $4 \times 5=20$. But that is not the answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Y and Z are sets that can have more than one element each

Comment: But isn't a ordered pair composed of two elements

Comment: For example, $Y = \{1,2,5\}$ is a single object and $Z = \{3\}$ is a single object, so the ordered pair $(Y,Z) = (\{1,2,5\}, \{3\})$ only has two objects in the pair.

Comment: Exactly. And the ordered pair means that $(\{1,2,5\},\{3\})$ and $(\{3\},\{1,2,5\})$ does count twice

Comment: Ah yeah you are right. I am always getting that one wrong...

Comment: By the way thanks you guys for those helpful responses

Comment: By the way, Theo Bendit has tried to give your question a better title but seems to have added a question that wasn't originally in your post.  If you are actually wanting to also know why the answer is $3^5$, then you may need to give some more context to the question.  For instance, there's a simple bijection between your collection of ordered pairs and the set of ordered triples (where the base $3$ comes in) of subsets which form a partition of $X$ (with five elements, so where the exponent $5$ comes in), but I have no clue if that solution would be appropriate.

Comment: @BrianMoehring This little subtlety was lost on me when I edited. I've limited the title only to what Rajesh was asking originally. Rajesh, if you do want to know why $3^5$ is the correct answer, please roll back my edit (and let Brian know so he can post a proper answer).

Comment: Hint: $(\text{first} \mid \text{second} \mid \text{neither})^5$

Comment: "But isn't a ordered pair composed of two elements" Ah, but elements of what? In this case they're subsets of $X$, making them elements of its [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

Comment: Hint for the right answer: Given $f:X\to\{0,1,2\}$, if $A=f^{-1}(0)$ and $B=f^{-1}(1)$ then $(A,B)$ is a pair of disjoint subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be getting confused in that $Y$ and $Z$ are sets (subsets of $X$), and can contain anywhere from $0$ to $5$ elements (not necessarily $1$ element).  The answer would indeed be $20$ if there were an additional restriction that $|Y|=|Z|=1$.  But there isn't, so we also need to count the cases when $Y$ and $Z$ don't have size 1.

A possible ordered pair is:
$$
(Y,Z) = (\{2,5\},\{1,4\})
$$
which is the same as saying $Y=\{2,5\}$ and $Z=\{1,4\}$ (and $3$ is in neither).

The way the question is phrased, any element in $X$ belongs to exactly one of:

- $Y$,
- $Z$, or
- $X \setminus (Y \cup Z)$, i.e., it's not in $Y$ nor $Z$.

For each of the $5$ elements of $X$, we decide whether to put it, and we have 3 options.